# Increase the performance by removing CLEAR ALL

Tags: performance, matlab

In `Matlab 2014b`, when I use `CLEAR ALL` at the beginning of the script I get the following warning,

```
For improved performance, consider not using CLEAR ALL within a script
```

which is not given in the previous releases (As I recall).

The only reason I found is that, when you call a script from outside or from other scripts you do not want to clear the variables in the workspace, and re-generate them every time again and again.

Is there any other reason that I am missing?

How does removing `CLEAR ALL` improves the performance when using a single script?

Comment: When using that single script once? Probably nothing. But ``clear all`` doesn't only clear variables, but also loaded functions and mex-functions (and, if i recall correctly, also breakpoints, which are set within that script). Those functions have to be loaded again (which simply costs a bit of time), the breakpoints are simply gone and will make it hard to debug a script, which starts with ``clear all``. To make sure to start with a clean workspace, ``clear variables`` should be sufficient.

Comment: I bet you don't get that warning if you use `clear`. The reason is that `clear all` clears functions too, as Nras explains. `clear` only cleans variables. Therefore compiled functions are kept in the memory. Have a [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873733/why-does-matlab-run-faster-after-a-script-is-warmed-up) for a bit more information. Amro's answer is especially interesting. =)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In R2015b, the semantics of `clear` were changed.  Perhaps in response to the concerns raised in this question, the [changes stated in the release notes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#busa1h6-21) are:

> The `clear` function no longer clears debugging breakpoints. To clear breakpoints, use `dbclear all`.
>
> The `clear` function only clears functions that are not currently running. For example, when you call `clear myFun` while `myFun` is running, `myFun` is not cleared.

---

This part pertains to pre-R2015b MATLAB versions.

[Here's a table](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html#input_argument_itemtype) of what gets cleared with each input argument.

[image]

The table for R2015b is identical except that there is no longer a "Debugging breakpoints" column since they are no longer cleared with `clear`.

Scripts and functions are cleared, when you can probably just `clear variables` (red boxes).  It does not make a lot of sense to clear the function from memory that is presently being executed. (According to R2015b release notes, this does not happen.)

Also, keeping in mind that **scripts execute in the base workspace**, you are clearing out all functions that may be used by *other scripts*.  Try looking at the output of `inmem` after an extended MATLAB tinkering session.  You fill find all kinds of MATLAB functions that are loaded into memory for fast access (including `'matlabrc'`, `'pathdef'`, and other core scripts that setup your workspace).  So, **perhaps it's not that it hurts performance of just the script where you call `clear all` but all other scripts and the interactive command line that is in the base workspace.**  That would be my guess.

Not performance related, but another reason why a `clear all` in a script might be a bad idea is that it will clear breakpoints (this can be annoying!), and global+persistent variables.  However, it might be the goal to clear global and peristent variables.  For global there's `clear global`, but there's nothing like that for persistent since persistent variables are bound to functions and you would use `clear functions` or `clear whateverFunctionName` for them.